# Within-group index (irregular groups)

Tags: r, split, vectorization, lapply

I have some data (irregular group labels) like `g`, and I want to obtain `k` -- i.e. within-group indices, via resetting cumsum.

```
g = c(1,1,1, 2, 3,3, 4, 5, 6,6,6,6,6, 7, 8, 9,9,9,9, 10, 11, 12, 13,13)
k = c(1,2,3, 1, 1,2, 1, 1, 1,2,3,4,5, 1, 1, 1,2,3,4,  1,  1,  1,  1, 2)
```

I have a working solution:

```
g.index = function(g){
  rep.i = c(F,diff(g)==0)
  k = numeric(length(g))
  for (i in 1:length(g)){
    if (rep.i[i]){ cs = cs + 1 } else { cs = 1 }
    k[i] = cs
  }
  return(k)
}
```

But I'm worried it will be slow due to loops versus vectorization. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Try with `data.table::rowid(g)` would be faster

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @akrun, use `data.table::rowid`

```r
g = c(1,1,1, 2, 3,3, 4, 5, 6,6,6,6,6, 7, 8, 9,9,9,9, 10, 11, 12, 13,13)
k = c(1,2,3, 1, 1,2, 1, 1, 1,2,3,4,5, 1, 1, 1,2,3,4,  1,  1,  1,  1, 2)

library(data.table)

all(rowid(g) == k)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. It is faster for roughly `length(g) > 100`.

Comment: Is there a similar function to get a matching vector of the totals, e.g. `c(3,3,3, 2,2, 1, 1, 5,5,5,5,5, ...)`?

Comment: One solution: `g.table = table(g); kmax = rep(g.table,times=g.table);`

Comment: A data.table solution could be `data.table(g)[, rep(.N, .N), g]$V1`. Note that `[.data.table` has high fixed overhead so this will be slow for small vectors but I'd guess should be much faster for at least `length(g) > 1e6`

Comment: Or with base R `with(rle(g), rep(lengths, lengths))`

Comment: Or with {collapse} + {magrittr} `collapse::fnobs(g, g) %>% rep(., .)`

Answer (score 0):

As with many things in R, you can't trust your intuition.

Here is a one-liner using `lapply` and `split`:

```
g.index.2 = function(g){
  k = unlist(lapply(split(rep(1,length(g)),g),cumsum))
}
```

We can see they give the same results using (graph below):

```
plot(g.index(g))
lines(g.index.2(g))
```

However, the first function is actually much faster. I'm not sure why.

```
N = 1e4
g = sort(ceiling(runif(N)*N/10))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark({g.index(g)},{g.index.2(g)},times=1e6/N)
```

```
Unit: microseconds
                 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 {       g.index(g) }  697.566  760.452 1078.655  907.409 1090.495  6857.132   100  a
 {     g.index.2(g) } 7722.124 8017.586 8325.830 8258.430 8563.026 10101.035   100   b
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can break your problem down into the following steps that compose into another one-line solution:

1. Determine run lengths using `rle()`
2. Generate an integer sequence for each run length using `seq_len()`
3. Concatenate the sequences into a single integer vector using `do.call(c, ...)`

```r
do.call(c, lapply(rle(g)$lengths, seq_len))
#>  [1] 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: Nice! The speed is: rowid > this > loop > split (see my self-answer below), without adding data.table. Plus `rle` gives the total lengths directly, which I also wanted, after.